# How much of concrete mathematics can be expressed in the language of category theory?

Tags: logic, category-theory, soft-question, foundations

## Question 1

How much of group/ring/lattice/... theory can be expressed in purely categorical terms (only using the notions *object*, *morphism*, *identity morphism*, and *composition*), that is, as properties of the category of groups/rings/lattices/...?

I know that the question is vague. Let me be a bit more precise.

For example, consider group theory. Whenever one proves a theorem $X$ about groups, one can ask: can $X$ be expressed purely in categorical terms? For instance, consider the following theorem $X$: "for each homomorphism $\varphi\colon G\to H$, there are homomorphisms

$$G\stackrel{\varphi_1}{\longrightarrow} G/\ker(\varphi)\stackrel{\varphi_2}{\longrightarrow}\text{im}(\varphi)\stackrel{\varphi_3}{\longrightarrow} H,$$

where $\varphi_1$ is surjective, $\varphi_2$ is an isomorphism, and $\varphi_3$ is injective." This theorem can be expressed purely in categorical terms, since each concept occurring in the theorem happens to have a categorical description: surjective --> [epimorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimorphism), injective --> [monomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomorphism), quotient --> [coequalizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coequalizer), [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(category_theory)), [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(category_theory)). In contrast to, for example, [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)): it contains the notion of the "order" of a group, which I guess cannot be defined in terms of morphisms and composition.

In fact, one can (more) precisely define what I mean by "in purely categorical terms": consider the [first-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) language $L$ consisting of two sorts, *objects* and *morphisms*, two function symbols $\text{dom}$ and $\text{cod}$ (from morphisms to objects), and a ternary relation symbol between morphisms $f, g, h$ expressing that $h = g\circ f$. Then for each first-order (or higher-order) sentence $\varphi$ in the language $L$ and each category $\mathcal C$, one can ask whether $\varphi$ is satisfied in $\mathcal C$, $$\mathcal C\models \varphi.$$
In this sense, one has defined a notion of a "property" $\varphi$ of a category. For example, one can write down an $L$-sentence $\varphi_1$ expressing the associativity of composition. Then each category $\mathcal C$ satisfies $\varphi_1$. Also, one can write down an $L$-sentence $\varphi_2$ expressing that "for all objects $A, B$, there is an object $A\times B$ satisfying the universal property of the product". Then a category $\mathcal C$ satisfies $\varphi_2$ if and only if $\mathcal C$ has products.

Lawvere demonstrated that essentially all theorems of *set theory* can be expressed in this limited language (surprise: we don't need a binary relation $\in$) and derived from a small number of axioms (written down in the language), see [ETCS](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ETCS).

Coming back to my question, I wonder how many theorems $X$ of group/ring/lattice/... theory can be expressed in this categorical language, in the sense that we can find an $L$-sentence $\varphi_X$ "expressing" $X$ (that is, $\mathcal C\models\varphi_X$, where $\mathcal C$ is the category of groups/rings/lattices/..., should be equivalent to $X$).

As another random example, can the spectral theorem of linear algebra, stating that an endomorphism $f$ is normal and triangularizable if and only if there is an orthonormal basis $B $consisting of eigenvectors of $f$, be expressed as a property of the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces?

## Question 2

A related question that is coming to my mind is the following: sometimes in mathematics, it happens that two categories, say $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal D$, studied in two different branches of mathematics, say $A$ and $B$, respectively, are shown to be equivalent. (For example, consider $A$ to be the study of commutative C*-algebras and $B$ the study of compact Hausdorff spaces.) *How much does this say about the similarity of $A$ and $B$ as mathematical branches?* If many questions and theorems can be expressed in the categorical language, this means that $A$ and $B$ are, as branches, essentially the same, since then each statement occurring in $A$ can be translated into the branch $B$ and vice versa. Otherwise (for example if some property of, say, Hausdorff spaces doesn't have a categorical analogue), this could mean that there can still be questions in the branch $B$ that cannot be translated into the branch $A$, therefore each of the two branches having its own right to exist.

Comment: I consider your last statement to be (slightly) dangerous. Just because things can be proven in both categories doesn't mean we should get rid of any of the two. Some things might be easier to understand in one language than in the other and in another case the other way round.

Comment: Another reason to have two different formulations of equivalent categories is that formulation #2 might have interesting generalizations which are hard to express in formulation #1. This happens a lot, and indeed this can even *drive* the study of equivalent reformulations of mathematical categories.

Comment: Crossposted: https://mathoverflow.net/q/344826/461